# gmake compile all files in a directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

we have some C++ code that we need to create a make file in. Each .h and .C pair create an object and then some objects are linked together to form a executable. Pretty standard stuff.

This non-gnu make command just builds all the files into object in a directory

```
%.o:%.C
    $(CC) $(CPFLAGS)  -c  $<
```

What this does is for each %.C file (ie every .C file) build a corresponding .o file.

Does anybody know how to do this with gmake?

Cheers

Mark

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The syntax you've shown is called a pattern rule in GNU make parlance, and it forms the corner stone of your solution.  All you need is to add a way to get the list of .C files dynamically.  Others have shown solutions that use `$(shell)` to do this, but that's needlessly inefficient.  I suggest you instead use $(wildcard), which is a GNU make built-in function designed for just this purpose:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.C)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.C,%.o,$(SRCS))
foo: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.C
        $(CC) $(CPFLAGS)  -c  $<
```

If you are looking for something more concise, the following will work too:

```
foo: $(patsubst %.C,%.o,$(wildcard *.C))
```

This just eliminates the variables and takes advantage of the fact that GNU make provides a default `%.o: %.C` pattern rule, as well as a default rule for linking an executable together from a set of objects.  Personally I would use the more verbose version as I find it easier to read and maintain, but to each their own.

Hope that helps,

Eric Melski

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a [pattern rule](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make.html#SEC91), it should work fine in `gmake`. For very simple builds like this you can mostly rely on the [implicit rules](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make.html#SEC88). The main thing you have to specify in the target you want to build and its dependencies:

```
CXXFLAGS:=-g -O -Iincludes
LDFLAGS:=-lm

SRCS:=$(shell ls *.C)          # select all .C files as source
OBJS:=$(substr .C,.o,$(SRCS)   # list the corresponding object files

foo : $(OBJS)
```

Note the use of [simply expanded variable](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make_toc.html#SEC62) assignment operator (`:=`) rather than the recursive assignment operator (`=`) which can reduce the amount of reprocessing make does in more complicated builds.

Comment: You're mistaken; the OP shows a standard pattern rule, not a static pattern rule, and there's no good reason for using $(shell) here where $(wildcard) will do the trick without the additional overhead.

Comment: @Eric: Correct about the static pattern rule, of course. Fixed. I use $(shell ) a lot despite the extra fork because I often generalize the command. By using := assignment I suffer he extra only once.

Comment: you can just as easily use := with $(wildcard) if you like.